# Verify PHP 5.3.27 has been patched for CVE-2013-4248

Tags: security, centos5, php5, rpm

Server setup:

- CentOS release 5.10 (Final)
- WHM 11.40.0 (26)
- EasyApache 3.22.24 rev9999 compiled apache 2.2.26 and PHP 5.3.27 w/ SuHosin 0.9.33

I already had PHP 5.3.27 installed (since before most of documents/patches for CVE-2013-4248 came out), so I'm not sure it's downloading the patched version from anywhere if it thinks it already has the newest version locally. Looking at the logs, this is what I'm afraid of.

Also, apparently there are only peripheral PHP RPM packages installed, so running a command like: `rpm -q --changelog php53`
yields a "no package" message.

the command
`php -v`
just gives me the gross output of the version number along with ioncube, etc. versions.

Is there a local changelog file a can check that would have the info I want? I simply can't find one with either the `find` command or by looking at the directories with core php files in them.

I am specifically looking for changes/patch(es) made toward fixing **CVE-2013-4248**.

Thank you,
I've spent several hours searching/reading on the web and still don't have an answer specific to my flavor of Linux/etc.

Answer (score 1):

You're using upstream PHP directly, rather than Red Hat's packages. While Red Hat has [backported the security fix](http://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2013-1307.html) to their own PHP packages, PHP themselves [have not](http://php.net/archive/2013.php#id2013-07-11-1) released a security fix. PHP only patched this issue [for 5.4 and 5.5](http://php.net/archive/2013.php#id2013-08-22-1), so you should either use Red Hat's packages, or update to 5.4/5.5.

Comment: As confirmed here: http://git.php.net/?p=php-src.git;a=commit;h=2874696a5a8d46639d261571f915c493cd875897